# The package evince needs to be reinstalled

Tags: evince

`sudo apt-get upgrade` gives me following error

```
E: The package evince needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried  `sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update`
result:

```
    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                             
...
...
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Edit:

```
   apt-cache policy evince
Gives:
evince:
  Installed: 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2
  Candidate: 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.2-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit2:

```
evince:
Installed: 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2
Candidate: 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2
Version table:
*** 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2 100
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    3.18.2-1ubuntu4 500
       500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
       500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 
 Packages
```

Tried:
Enable xenial-updates repository:

4.1. launch Software & Updates

4.2. on Ubuntu Software tab make sure you have checked first four marks, in Download from drop-down list select Main server (for more predictable results)

4.3. on Updates tab make sure you have checked two marks (Important security updates (xenial-security), Recommended updates (xenial-updates) )

4.4. Press Close and confirm Reload of package lists.

Got following error:

```
E:The package evince needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [The PPA your error mentioned](https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash) has no packages for Ubuntu 16.04,

Please remove the PPA if you have installed packages from it with this command:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
```

or remove it from your sources with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again to check everything is fixed.

2. Please update your question with `apt-cache policy evince` to determine its origin.
3. Clear APT cache and lists, then install evince again with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install evince
   ```
4. Enable xenial-updates repository:
   4.1. launch *Software & Updates*
   4.2. on *Ubuntu Software* tab make sure you have checked first four marks, in *Download from* drop-down list select *Main server*  (for more predictable results)
   4.3. on *Updates* tab make sure you have checked two marks (*Important security updates (xenial-security)*, *Recommended updates (xenial-updates)* )
   4.4. Press *Close* and confirm *Reload* of package lists.
5. Edit your */etc/apt/sources.list* with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and place the [contents of my file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26162943/) to it. You can comment your manually added repositories. Then start over.
6. Install aptitude and try `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -f` and `sudo aptitude reinstall -f evince`.

Comment: It fixed all ign from update, but the problem with evince is still there

Comment: See no. 3 above.

Comment: everything was good until upgrade, there still same error, when trying to install evince - same error.

Comment: Please update your `apt-cache policy evince` again in the question. It looks like you have disabled *xenial-updates* repository (it has *3.18.2-1ubuntu4.3* now).

Comment: How can I enable it ?

Comment: See updated no. 4 above.

Comment: got an error when loading packages

Comment: You can use my sources.list.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Install aptitude and try `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -f` and `sudo aptitude reinstall -f evince`.

Comment: I don`t really knw how, but I worked it out.
I deleted manually some packages from Sofware & Updates-> Other software tab. in terminal sudo apt-get -f install worked. After upgrade problem disappeared. 


Thank you very much for help!